# How to initiate an audio call from bot to user?

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-bots

Is it possible to initiate an audio call from Bot to the user? If yes, Could you please provide the sample code where i can refer.

Comment: To clarify, where you interested in doing this in v3 or v4 of the bot builder SDK?

Comment: I am interested to implement in v3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do so with use of MS Teams and Graph API.

Docs to help point you in the right direction:

- [Registering a calling bot for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot)
- Blog: [Build Your Teams Calling Bot (IVR application) with Microsoft Graph](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2018/12/19/microsoft-graph-teams-calling-bot-tutorial/#respond)

  - shows you raw REST call flows
- [v4 node sample with msgraph](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/bot.js)

  - although you're looking into v3, here's a sample that you can look at to see how they organized msgraph into their bot to help you get ideas of how you'd like to organize it in your own v3 bot